# Proving infimum and supremum of a set

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, solution-verification

Find the supremum and infimum of the set $E:=\left\{\frac{3}{n+2}+2\mid n \in \Bbb{N}\right\}$.

It's obvious that $$\frac{3}{n+2}+2 \leq 3, \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$$

So $3$ is an upper bound of $E$. Lets assume that $b$ is another upper bound for $E$, such that $b=3-\epsilon$, $\epsilon > 0$. If $b$ is an upper bound, then $b \geq x$ for all $x \in E$. However, $3 \in E$. Therefore $b$ is not an upper bound of $E$ and $\sup E=3$

As for the infimum. Since $$\frac{3}{n+2}+2 \geq 2, \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$$

So $2$ is a lower bound of $E$. Lets assume there is another lower bound $c=2+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon >0$. By the Archimedean property of real numbers, $$
\begin{split}
\frac{3}{n+2}   &< \epsilon\\
\frac{3}{n+2}+2 &< 2+\epsilon
\end{split}
$$

Thus $c$ is not a lower bound of $E$ and $\inf E=2$. 
Extending the idea of the Archimedean property to this expression seems intuitive to me ( we can always choose a natural number, such that the expression is smaller than a positive real number ) , but I would be hard pressed to find a precise explanation for its use here. What other flaws are in this proof?

Comment: For the $\sup$, it is sufficient to show that $3$ is an upper bound and that it is attained ($for $n=1$).

Comment: Looks ok to me. You don't need $\epsilon$ for the sup. Since 3 is an upper bound and a member of the set, it must be the least upper bound. For the inf, the Archimedean principle tells you that you can find $n$ such that ... . The inequality does not hold for all $n$ (but all you need is one such $n$).

Comment: $\frac{3}{n}<\epsilon$ for some $n$. Then $\frac{3}{n+2}<\frac{3}{n}<\epsilon$. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I think so. I used the fact that $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$, then applied it here.